# Net User $Variable /Delete

Tags: powershell

This is a non-domain environment that we manage with Microsoft InTune.

I need be able to do a `FOR` command that will delete all of the users from the Administrators group on the local PC using this CMD below that displays all of the users in the local Administrators group.

```
Net LocalGroup Administrators | Where {$_ -AND $_ -NotMatch "command completed successfully"} | Select -skip 4)
```

The above will show all users in the Administrators group on the local PC.

Comment: So, what have you tried? What doesn't work as expected?

Comment: On top of what Ansgar is asking. You say _delete all of the __users__ from the Administrators group on_. Did you mean to get rid of just users or groups as well?

Comment: @Matt no just the Administrators Group while Deactivating the user "Administrator".

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I have tried the following:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           `$Variable777 = @(Net LocalGroup Administrators | Where {$_ -AND $_ -NotMatch "command completed successfully"} | Select -skip 4)

Net User | ForEach ($Variable777 in $Variable777) {Delete}`